# Optaplanner inventory allocation

Tags: optaplanner, inventory

I am trying to work with Optaplanner in order to solve the following simple exmample :
https://www.gams.com/products/gams/gams-language/#the-gams-language-at-a-glance/
[simple inventory allocation exemple](https://www.gams.com/products/gams/gams-language/#the-gams-language-at-a-glance/)
I find it very difficult to do so since I couldn't find a similar cas on optaplanner

Can anyone help ? some directions, ressources

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [Facility Location Problem in OptaPlanner Quickstarts](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/facility-location), but a consumer can pull from 2 or more suppliers at the same time.

Because the number of units to ship from supplier A to consumer X is an integer (*), you would need to use *continuous value ranges* and *custom moves* like in [the investment example](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/investment). Not simple (unlike other use cases in OptaPlanner), but doable.

(*) These business requirements are maybe unrealistic: in the real world, a half-full truck is almost as expensive as a full truck.

Comment: Hello Geoffery,
Thanks a lot for your answer.
From my understanding a continuous value range is used when the planning variable is a double between 0.0 and 1.0 not when it’s an Integer (like our case).
In other words: can we use a planning variable X (number of cases) that is an Integer (we can’t break a case) and that has a discrete planning range?
Thanks a lot.